# Delegate won't work

Tags: objective-c, xcode, delegates

I have a simple delegate test, but for some reason it doesn't get called.

I want to call **`-(void)test`** from `AppDelegate` class via **delegate**.

/// AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@protocol AppDelegateDelegate
@required
-(void)test;
@end
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    id<AppDelegateDelegate> _delegate;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) id<AppDelegateDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

///  AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [_delegate test];
}
@end
```

/// test.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface test : NSObject <AppDelegateDelegate>
-(void)test;
@end
```

/// test.m

```
#import "test.h"
@implementation test
-(void)test {
    //this should be called from AppDelegate
    NSLog(@"delegate test");
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the delegate `test` method as soon as the `AppDelegate` class is loaded and no other class has had a chance to set themselves as the delegate.  You need to call the delegate method **after** another class has had a chance to set itself as the delegate.

Also your delegate property should be defined as:

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet id <AppDelegateDelegate> delegate;
```

Comment: Ok, I create -(IBAction)buttonCall:(id)sender { [delegate test]; }
so now there is enough time to let test set itseft to delegate guess.
I also init it before call delegate, and I changed property to @property (assign) IBOutlet id <AppDelegateDelegate> delegate; , test still not called

Comment: @user840250 And where does the `test` object set itself as the delegate?

Comment: Thanks, 
    test * testDelegate = [[test alloc] init];
    [self setDelegate:testDelegate];